# How to create jQuery dropdown menu with click function

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, click

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="navMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navMenu ul li").click(function() {  
    $(this).find('li ul.child').fadeToggle(400);
  });
});
```

Targeting the navMenu class clicking on `ul li`. Then I want it to find `li ul.child` where the links are located.

Comment: You don't have any `ul.child` elements

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you're attempting to `find()` an element that doesn't exist.

You can instead amend your code to `find()` the child `ul` and call `fadeToggle()` on it:

```js
$(".navMenu ul li").click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

```css
.navMenu > ul > li > ul { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can do this in CSS alone assuming you don't need to support IE7 and lower:

```css
.navMenu > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
}

.navMenu > ul > li > a:focus + ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will works for you because you are not applying JavaScript properly on any selector

```js
 $(".navMenu ul>li").click(function() {  
  $(this).children('ul').fadeToggle(400);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navMenu">
      <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navMenu ul li ul li").click(function() {  
    $(this).parent().children().fadeToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```